# Emacs Move Window Down

Tags: emacs

I have multiple windows open in emacs via `C-X 2`. However, sometimes I want to move a window at the top, down one, so that the window below it moves up, and that window I want to move goes down one place. I'm not talking about moving within windows, but moving the actual window. Is this possible in emacs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```lisp
(require 'buffer-move)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-up>")     'buf-move-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-down>")   'buf-move-down)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-left>")   'buf-move-left)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-right>")  'buf-move-right)
```

Comment: And the `buffer-move` library is...?

Comment: Turns out that I was wrong in thinking that it was part of Emacs:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/buffer-move.el